# « Ça vient me chercher » ?

Tags: sens, locutions, québec, synonymes

> J'aime le cinéma québécois parce que ce qui se fait ici est vraiment
>   bon, **ça vient me chercher**, me toucher. (Marie Chalifoux, dans [La
>   Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/cinema/cinema-quebecois/201603/14/01-4960502-avenir-du-cinema-quebecois-des-cegepiens-se-prononcent.php))

On trouve cette locution, *ça vient me chercher*, en parlant de sa réaction au sort d'une personne, aux évènements, à une situation, à une chose etc. On pensait que ça voulait dire *(me) toucher* (*être touché*), mais ici on a le verbe *toucher* qui suit et je pense qu'on évoque une nuance plutôt qu'un synonyme...

- Quelle est cette nuance ?
- À quel sens de [*chercher*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chercher), voire de [*venir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/venir), rattache-t-on le sens de la locution, qu'est-ce
  qui *cherche* quoi au juste ; est-ce que c'est formulé sur le modèle *être touché* mais de sens ou de degré différent ; est-ce que ça correspond vraiment à *être touché* ?
- Est-ce un régionalisme (du Québec) ?

Comment: Régionalisme: oui.

Comment: Québécisme. http://www.swing-la-bacaisse-dans-lfond-dla-boite-a-bois.com/p/lexique.html

Answer (score 3):

"*ça vient me chercher*", dans ce contexte, me fait "ressentir" immédiatement un synonyme tel que : "*ça me va droit au cœur*". Ce qui correspond à la nuance que vous évoquez, puisque là, on a également la notion "*d'intrusion*" (dans le cœur et l'esprit). On entre, puis on touche.

Dans le registre de l'émotion, je pense aussi à :

1. Ça m'apostrophe / ça me parle.
2. Ça me prend aux tripes (plutôt imagé et vraiment peu châtié).

Néanmoins, pour moi, ça ne comporte pas cette notion de "pénétration" de l'esprit telle que "*ça vient me chercher*" me l'inspire, puisque *apostropher / parler* peut se faire à distance, sans notion de mouvement/rapprochement.

Je ne me prononce pas sur le fait que ce soit un régionalisme, même si je le pense, car je n'ai pas de source pour le confirmer.

Answer (score 2):

*Me toucher* est une précision. *Ça vient me chercher* peut être interprété comme ceci:

> Ça cherche à éveiller *quelque chose* en moi [et ça a réussi].

C'est une expression fondamentalement assez vague et le contexte permet généralement de comprendre ce qu'on veut dire. Voici quelques exemples:

- (tristesse) Quand on parle de fleurs, ça vient me chercher. Ça me rappelle le décès de ma mère.
- (colère) Quand il fait ça, ça vient me chercher. J'ai le goût de le tabasser.
- (intérêt) J'ai modifié le design, tu en penses quoi? Ah oui, ça vient me chercher pas mal plus.

On peut faire un lien avec l'expression "Si tu me cherches [...]". Dans ce cas on pourrait parler d'impatience. Voici d'autres exemples trouvés sur Internet:

- ([haine](https://plus.lapresse.ca/screens/0312fdd0-6d71-48f6-87cc-d97d91595f62__7C___0.html)) Je sais bien. Mais j’ai de la misère avec La Pat’Patrouille ! Ça vient me chercher au plus profond de mon cœur à quel point j’« haïs » ça…
- ([colère](https://www.grenier.qc.ca/nouvelles/24008/dans-loeil-de-camila-hadji-tam-tamtbwa)) Une cause qui te tient à cœur : Toute forme d’injustice, d’oppression & d’intimidation. Ça vient me chercher à un autre niveau.
- ([intérêt](https://montreal.ca/articles/10-questions-alexandra-girard-bibliothecaire-ville-marie-7654)) J’adore la BD, les romans graphiques et la poésie nouvelle, qui représente notre réalité de façon crue. Ça vient me chercher.
- ([intérêt](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bju-2EOFmq3/) ou ému) Les pastels, ça vient me chercher.
- ([fier](https://naitreetgrandir.com/fr/chroniques/effet-miroir-mamie/) et ému) Pourquoi ça me touche autant? [...] C’est pour cette raison que ça vient me chercher autant. [...] J’ai un sentiment de fierté à me reconnaître en mes enfants, en Louka.
- ([impatience](https://www.tuac500.com/index.php/enjeux-500/batissons-la-releve-tuac500/9-uncategorised/184-batissons-la-releve-maxime-rivet) et énervement) Ça des fois ça vient me cherche[r] un petit [peu] plus. Des personnes qui ne se renseignent pas ou qui ne se renseignent pas aux bonnes personnes et qui utilisent ces informations qui sont souvent erronées et qui viennent te voir.
- ([colère](https://www.ledevoir.com/societe/596232/la-douce-intranquillite-de-dorothy-rhau)) Ça vient me chercher lorsque je me heurte à des gens qui nient notre réalité, nos histoires, nos obstacles ou qui pensent que parler des femmes, ça englobe nécessairement les femmes noires.

Answer (score 1):

De toute évidence, il s'agit d'un régionalisme québecois, par ailleurs plaisant et évocateur. Si vous souhaitez être plus littéraire et plus français, par exemple à la mode psychanalyste des années soixante-dix, vous pouvez dire "ça m'interpelle quelque part", une expression maintenant tellement galvaudée qu'il vaut mieux l'éviter.